# AngularJS RESTful Web Service - Add row to table without refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restful-architecture

I'm trying to add a new row to my table after save a new object.
The example is as follow:

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngResource"]);

// Controller
demoApp.controller("saveCategoryController", function($scope, saveCategoryService, categoriesService){
    $scope.categories = categoriesService.query();

    $scope.createCategory = function(){
        saveCategoryService.saveCategory($scope.category);
        // I want to avoid this method to refresh my table.
        // $scope.categories = categoriesService.query();

    };    
});

// Factory
demoApp.factory("saveCategoryService", function($resource){
    return $resource("/demopro/saveCategory", {}, {
        saveCategory: {
            method: "POST"
        }
    });
});

demoApp.factory("categoriesService", function($resource){
    return $resource("/demopro/categories", {}, {
        listAllCategories : {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    });
 });
```

Is there any way to do that without make again a query to my database in order to show the new row in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, logically you would return the saved object on save and add it to the current list:

```
$scope.createCategory = function(){
        var newCategory = saveCategoryService.saveCategory($scope.category);
        $scope.categories.push(newCategory);     
};
```

Comment: Can you give me a hand with this similar situation? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573582/angularjs-restful-web-service-delete-row-from-table

Comment: I like @andrunix second answer there. Use the id you are using in the delete call and remove the object in the collection based on that id.