# AngularJS RESTful Web Service - Delete row from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restful-architecture

I need to delete a row from my table but I don't want to reload or refresh all my table in order to see the updated rows.

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngResource"]);

// Controller
demoApp.controller("categoryController", function($scope,   deleteCategorieService, categoriesService){
    $scope.categories = categoriesService.query();

    $scope.deleteCategory = function(id){
        deleteCategoryService.deleteCategory({id: id});
        // I want to avoid this method to refresh my table.
        // $scope.categories = categoriesService.query();
    }; 
 });

// Factories
demoApp.factory("deleteCategorieService", function($resource){
    return $resource("/demopro/deleteCategory/:id", {}, {
        deleteCategory: {
            method: "DELETE",
            params: {id: "@id"}
        }
    });
});

demoApp.factory("categoriesService", function($resource){
    return $resource("/demopro/categories", {}, {
        listAllCategories : {
           method: "GET",
           isArray: true
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You have to use your categoryService has a serviceManager. He must support fetch, update and delete methods.When you call query(), the service must return an object. This way, you will receive a reference on the returned list, and not a copy of the list itself.
Now, calling yourService.delete, it must call the required rest service, and remove the desired item from the final list. If you're using a reference, it will update the controller, and then, the view.

Comment: An example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rw4z7zvs/1/ (Damned, JSFiddle  is not as easy as it must be!)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to make the server call to delete the item but, to simply remove it from the view without reloading the whole list from the server, loop through your $scope.categories looking for the id of the item you are deleting, when found, remove from the array.

```
var i = $scope.categories.length;
while (i > 0) {
  if ($scope.categories[i].id === id) {
    $scope.categories.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
  i--;
}
```

You can also do a positive loop which I normally do but I recently was told this back-to-front loop is supposed to be much faster. YMMV.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++) {
   if ($scope.categories[i].id === id) {
     $scope.categories.splice(i, 1);
     break;
   }
 }
```

If you are using 2-way binding in your view, the HTML should update without the item you just deleted without having to requery the entire collection.

Comment: Not required to look about id. First of all, not every object own an Id, then, reference comparison can be done using === operator.
    a = { foo: 'bar' }
    b = { foo: 'bar' }
    a === b // false
    b = a;
    a === b // true

So, in he can call the delete method using the object itself, and check on current iteration if object IS the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you want to avoid the flickering that happens when refreshing the list, just update the list in the success callback. Something like:

```
$scope.deleteCategory = function(id){
    deleteCategoryService.deleteCategory({id: id},
        function(success) {
            $scope.categories = categoriesService.query();
        });
};
```

Comment: Hi, I need to delete a category in the server side and delete its row in the client side. It means don't reload all table in the client side after delete category. Similar to splice() method but working with a parameter to make the delete.

Comment: Then after deleting the category in the server you can do what @andrunix answered in the success callback (so that you are sure you delete the category from the scope only if it was successfully deleted on the server). Although I don't understand why you need to do this, you can risk to have the data in the app and server out of sync.